# How to support multiple splitting characters like ',', ';', or '|' for Oracle's DBMS_UTILITY.COMMA_TO_TABLE + REGEXP_REPLACE

Tags: regex, oracle

I have this query that splits a comma-separated string and inserts each value into a row of a table along with default data:

```
DECLARE
  L_INPUT VARCHAR2(4000) := 'foo,bar,baz,wibble';
  L_COUNT BINARY_INTEGER;
  L_ARRAY DBMS_UTILITY.LNAME_ARRAY;
BEGIN
  DBMS_UTILITY.COMMA_TO_TABLE(LIST => REGEXP_REPLACE(L_INPUT, '(^|,)', '\1x'), TABLEN => L_COUNT, TAB => L_ARRAY);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(L_COUNT);
  FOR I IN 1 .. L_COUNT
  LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Element ' || TO_CHAR(I) || ' of array contains: ' || SUBSTR(L_ARRAY(I), 2));
    INSERT INTO INSTANCE VALUES (I, SUBSTR(L_ARRAY(I), 2), NULL, 0);
    COMMIT;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

I need to know how to support multiple splitting characters like ',', ';', or '|' all together? Basically, I don't understand how to modify the regex in the above query to address my requirement.

Comment: The regex in Your query is adding the comma(',') to the inputed string from the start and also to the end. I would suggest to write Your own function based on Your requirements for the getting the list of the elements from the input string.

Comment: @mikron It's not true. The regex adds 'x' to the begining of each token in a list

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex:

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE('foo,bar;baz|wibble', '[|;]', ',') from dual;
```

If you need the functionality of your current regex (adding 'x' to each token) then use:

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE('foo,bar;baz|wibble', '[|;]', ','), '(^|,)', '\1x') from dual;
```

Comment: Good idea regarding sanitizing the input string and replace ; and | with a comma